# Browser extension: how to secure API calls

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, api-design

I am working on a browser extension which is supposed to exchange (GET and POST) data with my MEAN server (-> node.js). I was wondering on how to secure the server-side API routes in order to avoid DDOS attacks and similar threats arising from bypassing my extension and directly sending/requesting data by malicious software/servers/individuals.

I intend to employ several tokens that have to be included in each call (GET/POST via HTTPS connection):

- static extension ID hash which is invisibly hard-coded inside my extension and white-listed on the server side, such as ext_id: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
- limiting the amount of request per user/extension in a given period of time
- hashed and salted user credentials (provided by the user via an input field inside the extension preferences and stored locally), like username: e3b0c44298fc1c149[...], password: da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfe[...]

I was hoping for some input and constructive criticism by experienced experts in this area to approve or enhance this approach or maybe even proposing reasonable alternatives.

Comment: This question may receive a more detailed answer on the [Information Security StackExchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/). If you do ask such a question there, at least leave a link to it in this question.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to be able to quickly discard invalid requests. The highest return on investment you'll get is through caching and through having progressive delays.

That said, one thing you can do is hash or encrypt a value with each request, combined with a timestamp. This means that each request the client makes will have a unique value that is based upon the time it was submitted, so each request they make will need to be unique. This also provides a bit of extra security for the user, in preventing replay attacks.

Answer (score 0):

> in order to avoid DDOS attacks

API level restrictions help against DoS attacks exploiting slow (resource-intensive) APIs. For that case a simple login requirement and per-user rate limiting should be sufficient.

They are useless against attacks that simply saturated your network connection, kernel resources (TCP connections) or attack the TLS layer (encryption handshakes) or the network IO part of your application.

> arising from bypassing my extension and directly sending/requesting data by malicious software/servers/individuals.
>
> [...] ID hash which is invisibly hard-coded inside my extension

Essentially, what you're plannning there is not possible. The browsers use open protocols and are debuggable. Anything an extension sends can be replicated by a script.

Trying to somehow make the extension special that it can't be replicated by external software you're basically asking to invent unbreakable DRM.

Comment: Ok, got it so far... instead, you suggest I should be doing what? =)

Comment: see my 2nd sentence